# Hungary 1956 or Czechoslovakia 1968 this is not

Tags: word-order

Source: [Is Putin Winning?](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/04/opinion/sunday/ross-douthat-is-putin-winning.html?_r=0)

Example:

> A Russia that can’t control what happens in Kiev is not exactly poised to dominate Eastern Europe; **Hungary 1956 or Czechoslovakia 1968 this is not**.

The grammar looks a little bit nonstandard. *Hungary 1956 or Czechoslovakia 1968* is supposed to go after *this is not*. What do you think is going on here?

Comment: I think it's used for an effect, though I'm not sure about the name of the structure (fronting, perhaps?). Anyway, it sounds fine to me. Here is a similar example: [Silicon Valley, this is not.](http://www.denverpost.com/carman/ci_15139997)

Comment: Master Yoda of Star Wars is known to speak in this manner.

Comment: @shin: meant you I think "Known in this manner to speak Master Yoda of Star Wars is", hmmmmm? :-)

Comment: Because Yoda speak never crossed my mind, so I looked for more info about the structure itself. I've looked and found it on a page that's not available on Google Books. However, [this page](http://languagetools.info/grammarpedia/dislocation.htm) has similar information. I believe that this structure is called **preposing**, or to be more specific: **complement preposing**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is grammatically correct.  While less common, this change in the typical order is called [hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton#English) and is not that unusual.  It's typically used for emphasis.

The semantic meaning of the bolded sentence is identical to:

**This is not Hungary 1956 or Czechoslovakia 1968.**

but with the hyperbaton the implied disparity between "this" and "Hungary 1956 or Czechoslovakia 1968" feels greater.

As far as what is going on grammatically, I think it's nothing more than the flexible word order afforded by English.

**I am not a fool.**

**A fool I am not.**

Both are correct.

Comment: [This is ***not*** inversion!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78592/is-this-correct-aloof-the-hallow-things-shall-always-be/78595#78595)  Only in clauses where the verb comes before the subject have you inversion, like in this sentence. That isn’t happening here.

Comment: I wasn't using "inversion" in the technical sense, but in the dictionary sense: "a change in the position, order, or relationship of things".  Nevertheless, you are right that it's confusing on a language site.  I'll update to use the correct term, which I wasn't aware of.  Thanks.